# Can I mount a Nikon 50 mm f1.8 series E pancake lens on an Nikon D7000?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount

Hello I have a Nikon D7000. I would like to know if I can mount a Nikon 50mm f/1.8 Series E old manual lens on this body? Will the meter system work with it? I also have a Vivitar Series One 70mm-210mm f/2.8 Nikon AI-S lens. Will that work on a Nikon D7000? I do not want to damage the mount of the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Series E lenses¹ are also AI-S lenses. Your Nikon D7000 can use AI-S lenses with manual focusing and automatic exposure. You may be asked to enter the lens' focal length and f-stop into the camera's menu in order to use Matrix metering. Center Weighted Averaging and Spot metering should work without having to enter anything.

If your Vivitar Series One 70-210mm f2.8-4 is also an AI-S type lens it should be safe to mount on your D7000. The lenses you need to be concerned about are the "pre-AI" lenses made before 1977. There are six different versions of the Vivitar Series One 70-210mm. The first two versions were a constant f/3.5 aperture. The third through sixth versions were f/2.8-4. Version three debuted in 1984 and all Nikon versions should be AI or AI-S.

<sub>¹ [Series E lenses](https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/nikortek.htm#e), a budget lens line from the late film era, should not be confused with more recent ['E' type](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000004725&configured=1&lang=en_US) lenses with electronically controlled apertures. They are two very different types of lenses. Series E are manual focus only AI-S lenses that can be used on pretty much any Nikon F mount camera. 'E' type lenses are new lenses with electronically controlled apertures that can only be controlled by Nikon DSLRs made since about 2007. On older cameras, including all F mount film cameras, the aperture can not be stopped down and will always stay wide open when 'E' type lenses are used.</sub>